# MPRemoteCommandCenter not receiving command triggers

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, record, mpremotecommandcenter

I have setup a function like this

```
 func setupRemoteCommandCenter(enable: Bool) {
    do{
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, mode: AVAudioSessionModeDefault, options: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.allowBluetooth)
    }
    catch {
        print("Setting category failed.")
    }
    let remoteCommandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()

    remoteCommandCenter.pauseCommand.isEnabled = enable
    remoteCommandCenter.playCommand.isEnabled = enable
    remoteCommandCenter.stopCommand.isEnabled = enable
    remoteCommandCenter.togglePlayPauseCommand.isEnabled = enable

    if enable {
        remoteCommandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(airPodsTap))
        remoteCommandCenter.playCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(airPodsTap))
        remoteCommandCenter.stopCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(airPodsTap))
        remoteCommandCenter.togglePlayPauseCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(airPodsTap))


    } else {

        remoteCommandCenter.pauseCommand.removeTarget(self, action: #selector(airPodsTap))
        remoteCommandCenter.playCommand.removeTarget(self, action: #selector(airPodsTap))
        remoteCommandCenter.stopCommand.removeTarget(self, action: #selector(airPodsTap))
        remoteCommandCenter.togglePlayPauseCommand.removeTarget(self, action: #selector(airPodsTap))

    }


}
```

Following apple documentation but I'm not able to consistently receive events from an external headset (wired / or bluetooth).

I already enabled audio background mode in my project settings.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've the same issue, someone can help us?